# Help finding a children's book about a pet dragon who eats baked beans from a skip

Tags: identification-request

A fully drawn book from the 90s in the UK.

It is about someone who had a pet dragon (iirc), and how it needed to eat a whole skip's worth of baked beans and other foods each night. I think it was quite a square aspect ratio binding, and not a large book.

Comment: [*The Dragonsitter*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/13154202) has a dragon that consumes baked beans, but it looks like it was first published in 2012.

Comment: @SeanDuggan thanks, doesn't seem so